# sed replace and add multiple lines with html code

Tags: bash, sed

Ive been trying various solutions but none seem to be working for me, so time to call the experts.

I have an index.html file that will be updated with a bash script to add new HTML code to. The bash script will be using a variable as part of the sed line. I would like it to find the following line

```
<!--insert_new_code-->
```

and then replace that line with

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div w3-include-html="explorers/$VARIABLE.html"></div>
  </div>

    <!--insert_new_code-->
```

So if I run the sed command 3 times it would look like this

```
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div w3-include-html="explorers/1.html"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div w3-include-html="explorers/2.html"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div w3-include-html="explorers/3.html"></div>
      </div>

   <!--insert_new_code-->
```

found the solution.

```
sed -i -e '/<!--insert_new_code-->/i\          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">\n            <div w3-include-html="explorers/'"${coin_name}"'.html">\n          </div>\n\n' index.html
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow.  Nice that you illustrated what result you need to accomplish.  Quite well explained.  Ima guessing folks are going to want to help you with this but to make that possible, what BASH code have you written which is not doing what you need it to do?  What is your question?

Comment: Hi, just found my solution and posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` script:

```
sed -e '/insert_new_code/i\<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">\
        <div w3-include-html="explorers/1.html"></div>\
      </div>\

' index.html
```